# AWS CloudSearch Dynamic fields aren't mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have an index field with a name of "*_i" (without quotes) on AWS CloudSearch:
[image: *_i dynamic field]

I then have the following document:

```
[
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "file_3",
    "fields": {
      "tenant_id": 1,
      "file_id": 3,
      "file_name": "TestWordDoc.docx",
      "file_size": "10795",
      "file_created_date": "2015-11-13T17:05:33Z",
      "file_contents": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog pdf",
      "file_custom_field_2_text": "This is a file text custom field value",
      "review_rating_i": 123
    }
  }
]
```

But when I try to upload the search document to AWS it doesn't match the dynamic field with "review_rating_i":

[image: aws refusing to match dyno field]

What am I doing wrong? I followed the instructions as per the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/using-dynamic-fields.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you just ignore the message and Upload Documents?
I think you may be able to search with Search Fields: review_rating_i

Comment: this should be comment in question rather than answer as more prominently it's a suggestion to try out what you mentioned and not the solution  that you tried yourself or sure enough to post it as answer.

Comment: @ForceHero you accepted the answer that is no more than a suggestion. Would you care to explain how you uploaded the document which you had problem with? 

How did you force upload? because using aws CLI it is not possible to upload forcibly.